# Magento - Sage Pay System error

Tags: magento, opayo

Recently we moved hosting providers and our Sage Pay module started throwing an error, once you try to submit a payment.

Sage pay error log contains:

```
The error details are: 2003 : An ERROR has occurred on the Sage Pay System.
```

Has anyone experienced this error before?

[Magento ver. 1.5.1.0]

Answer (score 0):

You've changed host so your site is now on a new IP - the IP for the old server is the one which is listed in the MySagePay panel, so you need to login to Sage and change it to the IP for your new server.  That's my guess anyway.

Comment: I already had that error and the message was different, I added the IP to the safe/approved IP list and the error was resolved but then this error (described above) started

Comment: This might be a daft question but - this is a live site, right? And which payment method are you using? (ie server-server)

Comment: I'm using the standard payment method where the user pays on the SagePay website and get directed back to the website.